Python typing warning when overriding a method with different returns depending on parameters
Here is an example of my issue
from typing import Literal, overload

@overload
def do_something(a: str, b: str="", no_return: Literal[False]=False) -> str: ...

@overload
def do_something(a: str, b: str="", no_return: Literal[True]=True) -> None: ...

def do_something(a: str, b: str="", no_return: bool=False) -> str| None:
    return None if no_return else "OK"

# The two use cases
a = do_something("") # a should be "OK"
b = do_something("", no_return=True) # b should be None

In this case, I have an error at the first do_something overload

Overload 1 for "do_something" overlaps overload 2 and returns an incompatible type

This seems like a very basic usage of typing to me, but I could not find a way to properly type this function. I have found a few other posts about similar issues, but every time the answer was roughly "it's just that way".
What is the way to do this? Am I trying to break some basic rule here?
Edit: I added params to the start of the method, as a proposed solution only seems to works without them.

Which type checker are you using that gives you this error?

Consider what happens if you call do_something() - that is, with no arguments. How can overload 2 (no_return: Literal[True] = True) ever be hit?

@dROOOze Does it need to be hit ? I thought overload is used to specify different behaviors.

@mkrieger1 I am using pylance's "standard" type checking mode

An overload specifies a behaviour when the arguments match the signature of the overload. do_something() will only ever match overload 1, so overload 2's behaviour (-> None) never activates. The type-checker warns you of this. Just remove =True to fix.

@dROOOze Thanks. However, I think I oversimplified the example. In my actual code, I have more parameters for the function, several of which have default values. no_return is the last one, which means I can't remove its default value without removing it from every other param. If I do that, Pylance rejects uses of this function without every param provided. Do I have to write overrides for every possible combination of params ?

You could make no_return a keyword-only argument. eg. (a: str, b: str = '', *, no_return: bool) -> str | None. Does change how the function may be called though.

You need to remove the default value for when the literal is True. Otherwise, the type checker is unable to figure out if do_something('') will use the literal false overload or the literal true overload.
As you have preceding default arguments, you cannot simply remove the default for no_return. However, if you make no_return keyword-only, then you can safely remove the default. This however, does mean do_something('', '', True) is no longer a covered by the overloads, and will lead to a type checking error.
from typing import overload, reveal_type, Literal

@overload
def do_something(a: str, b: str = '', no_return: Literal[False] = False) -> str: ...
@overload
def do_something(a: str, b: str = '', *, no_return: Literal[True]) -> None: ...
def do_something(a: str, b: str = '', no_return: bool = False) -> str | None:
    return a if no_return else None

# As reported by mypy
reveal_type(do_something(''))                   # note: Revealed type is "str"
reveal_type(do_something('', no_return=False))  # note: Revealed type is "str"
reveal_type(do_something('', no_return=True))   # note: Revealed type is "None"
reveal_type(do_something('', '', False))        # note: Revealed type is "str"

reveal_type(do_something('', '', True))
# error: No overload variant of "do_something" matches argument types 
# "str", "str", "bool"  [call-overload]


This does work for my purpose, thank you very much.
Although I am still confused as to why this seemingly simple need produces such a complex solution. Python typing seems way less efficient than Typscript as far as I can tell.

Typescript is older than python's type annotations. That's one reason why it might be more expressive. Another reason is that Python's syntax is more expressive. It allows you to combine positional and keyword arguments in the same call, whereas this is not possible in typescript. Or at least not without overloads. eg. It's not easy to express a function that can do all of f(0, ''), f(x=0, y=''), f(0, y=''), f(), f(0), f(x=0), and f(y='') in typescript. In python this is trivial, and doesn't require overloads. It's just (x: int = 0, y: str = '') -> None.

I think what you seem to be missing is whether do_something() should return value or not. According to your overloads it both does and does not return a value. Your type checker wants you to be specific about that return type.
